# Javascript caching issue with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session

I have installed `gem 'auto-session-timeout'`  to automatically log users off of inactive sessions. I want to give the user a 2 minute warning before the session times out

I added the following to my application.html.erb

```
 <%= javascript_tag do %>
       var d = new Date('<%= session[:auto_session_expires_at] %>');
       setInterval(function(){
                     var d = new Date('<%= session[:auto_session_expires_at] %>');
                    var e = new Date();
                    var f = e.getTime();
                    var diff = d - f ;
                    alert(d + " |  " + diff);

      if (diff <  120000) {
        //  alert("Your session is about to timeout in less than 2 minutes " + diff);
                        }
          }, 10000);

  <% end %>
```

My goal is to use the `if (diff < 120000)` statement to show an alert 2 minutes from logout.

The code above gets the session variable set by auto-session-timeout and then subtracts it from the current date (from js's getTime()) and comes up with a diff.

It is ALMOST working properly. If interact with the app, the counter gets reset. However, it seems like the old counter keeps running.

In other words if I look at the results of the alert statement that is not remarked out, I can see the datetime that is in  the session variable and the calculated diff. Below I am only showing the minutes and sessions that are shown for simplicity.

25:22   168134 -- first alert box - shows the contents of the session var and also shows the calculated diff or milliseconds remaining.

25:22   143249 -- second alert box -- everything is as expected.

25:22   120816  --  So, it is counting down correctly with the correct info from the session variable

Now, if I interact with the app, auto session timeout resets the session variable auto_session_expires_at.

26:13   158345 -- OK - exactly what I would expect . The Javascript is picking up the new session variable and it recalcualtes the diff.

25:22   86327 -- BUT now I'm seeing the previous session variable and the diff calculator is still running

The cycle above will then keep repeating between the 'good' and 'old' session variable and diff.  I think there is some kind of caching going on but I can't pinpoint it.

this behavior is repeatable for me

=======================================================
HTML from when I first open the app

```
/<![CDATA[


      var d = new Date('2016-05-06 15:58:19 -0400');

      setInterval(function(){

                    var d = new Date('2016-05-06 15:58:19 -0400');
                    var e = new Date();
                    var f = e.getTime();
                    var diff = d - f ;
                   alert(d + " |  " + diff);


      if (diff <  120000) {
        //  alert("Your session is about to timeout in less than 2 minutes " + diff);
                        }
          }, 10000);




//]]>
```

HTML from after I click on a nav item. You can see that the date grabbed from the session variable changes

```
/<![CDATA[


      var d = new Date('2016-05-06 15:58:48 -0400');

      setInterval(function(){

                    var d = new Date('2016-05-06 15:58:48 -0400');
                    var e = new Date();
                    var f = e.getTime();
                    var diff = d - f ;
                   alert(d + " |  " + diff);


      if (diff <  120000) {
        //  alert("Your session is about to timeout in less than 2 minutes " + diff);
                        }
          }, 10000);




//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: When you say that the session is reset after you interact with the site, are you being redirected? I ask this because it would be useful to see the generated HTML code.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been a bit fuzzy. What I was doing was choosing something from the nav menu since that loads a new page.

Comment: Ok, can you post the generated HTML to check the javascript function?

Comment: Ok - the html goes to heck in the comments. I'm adding it to my question

Comment: Another question, you said: `this behavior is repeatable for me`, are you getting 2 alerts, one with the old date and another with the new date?

Comment: Yes, once I interact with the app, I start getting alerts with the new expiration time plus alerts for the old expiration time. It seems that the original clock is still running

Comment: Then you should save the reference of the original `setTimeInterval` and then call `clearInterval` to make sure it doesn't keep running after you interact with the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SanF was right about the clearInterval. Here is the revised code. It's a lot different from what I started out with.

```
<% if current_user  %>

  <%= javascript_tag do %>


      // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // This script enhances the functionality of the auto_session_timeout gem
      //
      // this script will give the user a warning at a specified time before they will be automatically logged out
      // from their session.
      //
      // The polling interval is set in var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 10000); where 10000 = 10 seconds
      // That should be set to about 1000 so that the login screen appears as soon as possible when
      // the user comes to a screen from a timed out session.
      //
      // The time before logout for the warning is set in  if (diff <  120000)  120000 = 120 seconds
      //
      //  The timeout itself is contrlled by the auto_session_timeout gem and the setting in the application
      //  controller ' auto_session_timeout 4.minutes' . Make sure that the time set there is LONGER than the
      // time set below for the warning
      // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

              clearTimer();                                                       // clear the warning timer if it has been set previously
              var diff = 0;                                                       // Initialize the difference calculation
              var b = new Date();
              var f = new Date();
              var e = new Date();
              var current_time = e.getTime();                                     // get the current time from the system
              expires = new Date('<%= session[:auto_session_expires_at] %>');     // get the expiration time set by auto session expires.
              var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);                             // this calls myTimer and runs it at intervals specified. 1000 = 1 second


      // ------------------------------------ myTimer --------------------------------------------------
      // This function is called with a setInterval so that it runs at a set interval depending on the number
      // passed to var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000); above. It gets the session variable
      // containing the expires at date/time and also the current time. If the difference is less than the value set
      // a warning is shown via an alert box and then the function is cleared.
      // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          function myTimer() {
                   var diff = 0;                                                              // Initialize the difference between expires date/time and current date/time
                   var expires_raw = '<%= session[:auto_session_expires_at] %>'               // Get the raw session variable from rails
                                                                                              // we need to parse the date above to be like var d = new Date('2016-05-10T13:50:12-04:00');
                   var exp_date = expires_raw.slice(0,10);                                    // grab the date
                   var exp_time = expires_raw.slice(11,19);                                   // grab the time  H M S
                   var exp_tzh = expires_raw.slice(20,23);                                    // grab the hour part of the timezone with the -
                   var exp_tzm = expires_raw.slice(23,25);                                    // grab the minute part of the timezone which should be 00
                   var expires_parsed = exp_date + "T" + exp_time + exp_tzh + ":" + exp_tzm;  // Parse it all together. Date plus a constant 'T' , time, time zone hour, colon, timezone min
                   var expires_parsed_time = new Date(expires_parsed);                        // take expires_parsed and create a date/time from it
                   var expires_parsed_time_iso = expires_parsed_time.toISOString();           // Convert expires_parsed_time to an ISO string - This step is KEY to making this
                                                                                                 // work with IE 11 and firefox. They need the date from a strict ISO format
                   var expires_final = new Date(expires_parsed_time)                          // create a date from the expires_parsed_time
                   var expires_parsed_final = new Date(expires_parsed_time)                   // This is the final date that is fed to the diff variable


                  var e = new Date();                                                         // set up a new date for the current time
                  current_time = e.getTime();                                                 // get the current time from the system
                  diff = expires_parsed_final - current_time ;                                // calculate the difference between the expires and current times.

            // The following commented alert can be uncommented as a debugging tool

//                                    alert("\n raw date        " + '<%= session[:auto_session_expires_at] %>' +
//                                    "\n exp parsed      " + expires_parsed +
//                                    "\n diff            " + diff +
//                                    "\n current_time    " + current_time +
//                                    "\n exp raw         " + expires_raw +
//                                    "\n exp date        " + exp_date +
//                                    "\n exp time        " + exp_time +
//                                    "\n exp tzh         " + exp_tzh +
//                                    "\n exp tzm         " + exp_tzm +
//                                    "\n exp par time    " + expires_parsed_time +
//                                    "\n exp par tm iso  " + expires_parsed_time_iso +
//                                    "\n exp par final   " + expires_parsed_final);

      if (diff <  180000) {
            alert("\n Your Internal complaints session is about to timeout \n in less than 3 minutes  \n \n " +
                  "Please save your work  \n" +
                  "Navigating to any page will reset the timeout timer");
                  clearInterval(myVar);                                                     // this clears the current warning timer since the message has already been shown to the user.
            }
      }


      //   ------------------------------------ clearTimer ------------------------------------------
      //   When called, this function will stop the setInterval for myTimer so that we don't have
      //   multiple timers running
      //   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            function clearTimer() {
            clearInterval(myVar);
            }


            function myTest() {
            alert("test inside the test");
            }

  <% end %>
```

One other problem I ran into was that Firefox and IE use a strict interpretation of the ISO standards for dates. That required a few extra steps to use the ISO 8601 format for the date before trying to date arithmetic in IE/FF.

This still needs a little work but perhaps it could help someone trying to do a similar 'prior to timeout' warning.